# Dialogflow: how to automatically translate intents via Google Translate API over user requests

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-translate, translate, language-translation, google-translation-api

I'm really stuck at the process of auto-translation...

There is someone who can do a clear tutorial on how to automatically translate intents via Google Translate API over user request?

Searching all over the internet and haven't found anything clear...

I just need that if a Spanish user (for example) writes to my chatbot, the source language where the dialogflow agent is programmed is automatically translated to the detected one (Spanish in this case)

Comment: Have you looked into Dialogflows Multilingual agent feature? https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-multilingual

It allows you to just create a spanish version of your agent, this way you only have to enter the responses in spanish once, instead of having to google translate every request.

Comment: The fact is, i'm facing multiple intents and entities. I need my chat to do this automatically giving the response in the user's language on any platform (because it will mainly be used on facebook), As far as i know, in facebook you can't even change the bot language if not automatically made via wehook. I've seen someone have made that in facebook app but obviously no one is giving a clear tutorial on how to make this works

Comment: As far as i know, i need to write something in the firebase section to let the API recognise the user language and to get the proper response, translate it, and send it back. [Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9suqX8kTjk), this video explains in a much easier way the thing that i need